# Following .js code works on my terminal but not on website editor

Tags: javascript

I'm really scratching my head on this one. I was using an online javascript editor that would refuse to add to MySet the given character string, however IN MY editor (terminal and node .js) it works. I think it might be a dependency issue, but I thought sets were simply included in the standard javascript library. Any suggestions?

```
function isIsogram(text) {

var stringy = text;


var MySet = new Set();


for(i=0;i<stringy.length;i++)
{
  console.log(stringy.charAt(i));
  MySet.add(stringy.charAt(i));
}


console.log(MySet, stringy.length);

}


console.log(isIsogram('I eat zobs'));
```

Comment: which online editor is that one you are using?

Comment: admittedly it is for a school (and is proprietary - sorry about that) - HOWEVER, I think in this case it is ok to ask for advice as I think maybe their editor may be broken. Does it work in your terminal as well or is mine just crazy?

Comment: in my terminal it worked ok

Comment: What browser are you using for the online editor?